# Lambda cold start - copy file from S3

Tags: aws-lambda

I've got a Java lambda which is currently copying a file from S3 to /tmp. This is taking 6-10s depending on the size of the Lambda instance. The file is re-used on new invocations that use the same Lambda instance. However, traffic is very spiky and I could see 50+ simultaneous requests come in and the cold start copy from S3 is unacceptable...

Is there a better way to "pre-load" data into a Lambda instance than copying from S3? How about an HTTP request to grab a cached copy out of Cloudfront. Any other 'tricks' to speed up cold starts when there is initial startup data requirements?

**Answer: YES** See below

Comment: How large is this file?

Comment: The specific file in question is 1.5MB which I was pulling from S3 using GetObject. I decided to deploy my file(s) to my hosting bucket fronted by CloudFront and using Gzip and try this HTTP(s) request to pull the data into the Lambda. Great news, I got it working and I saw my Lambda initialization time drop from 12-15 seconds to about 4 seconds (using a 640MB) instance and writing the https file stream to /tmp in 16K chunks. Chunk size doesn't seem to matter much in my testing but I wanted to limit memory allocation in the Lambda. I'll edit my question and post the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer: YES**

It's faster to pull from an S3 hosting bucket fronted by CloudFront and using GZip. On a 1.5MB file I saw a performance improvement from 12 seconds to only 4 seconds. Here is the code I wrote for this purpose:

```
void getFile(String remoteUrl) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL(remoteUrl); 
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

    BufferedInputStream bis;
    if ("gzip".equals(con.getContentEncoding())) {
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(con.getInputStream()));
    }
    else {
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
    }

    String getPath = url.getPath();
    String fileName = "/tmp/"+getPath.substring(getPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
    byte[] buff = new byte[16 * 1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = bis.read(buff)) > 0)
        out.write(buff, 0, len);
    bis.close();
    out.close();
}
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Cliff

Comment: Above code assumes an HTTPS URL. Further performance improvements might be made using HTTP (use at your own risk!)